# If else condition not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in angularjs, I am getting employment status and i just want if i am getting employement status equal to HALFTIME then PartTime text should be display,Here is my code but not working,showing me nothing,where i am wrong ?

```
<h2 ng-if="{{myprofile.myJobs[0].employmentType}}==HALFTIME">
Part Time
</h2>
```

Comment: Enclose `HALFTIME` in quotes.

Comment: You don't use `{{}}` interpolation in `ng-if`. And is HALTIME a scope variable or is it supposed to be string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
<h2 ng-if="myprofile.myJobs[0].employmentType == 'HALFTIME'">
    Part Time
</h2>
```

You don't need curly braces inside `ng-if`

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use interpolation `{{ var }}`.

```
<h2 ng-if="myprofile.myJobs[0].employmentType == HALFTIME ">
    Part Time
</h2>
```